# Why there is no "User timing" section in my Chrome DevTools

Tags: devtools

According to this article:
[Debugging React performance with React 16 and Chrome Devtools.](https://building.calibreapp.com/debugging-react-performance-with-react-16-and-chrome-devtools-c90698a522ad)

I want to inspect some performance things of my own website built by React as well.
But I cannot see the **User timing** section in my DevTools.
Chrome version with 62.0.3202.89 in my computer,
am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: What if it is not a react application. And i don't see User timing section in my devtools?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to make this work by appending `?react_perf` to my url. Not sure why this was so difficult to find... hope it works for you.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html#profiling-components-with-chrome-timeline

Comment: Also note that `?react_perf` timeline feature in React only works in local development, since it gets compiled out of React’s production build.

Answer (score 12):

The User Timing tab was removed from chrome in favour of the "Timings" tab which combines some well known timings, such as LCP, OnLoad Event and custom User Timing API marks/measures.

Comment: where is Timings tab I can't see it

Comment: @Ehsansarshar it should show up under the Performance Tab in Chrome DevTools. By default, it is between Frames & Main, but I'm not sure if the order is customisable.

Comment: I think the main question is also this. the Timing is not appearing between Frames and Main

Comment: Yes it could be. In my case I was expecting a User Timing tab, which has since been combined with the Timings section. There is another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435791/timings-tab-in-chrome-performance-profiler-missing related to the missing Timing section. I hope it is helpful, however including `?react_perf` shouldn't make this visible as the Timings tab is visible for all sites.

Comment: refreshing the page will appear the timing tab.
but there is not any react flame chart. there are just some labels

Comment: The React specific flame chart is visible using the following extension under the Profiler tab: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en . The performance tab recording will show the flame chart (not React specific) for the main thread under the Main section.

Comment: there is a browser timing api that frameworks like React.js call internally which log the result in the timing section inside performance tab.
the React devtools also have it's flame chart. but I am looking for the one inside performance tab

Comment: OK understood what you refer to: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab . And can you confirm you are running in development mode?

Answer (score 9):

You need to add `?react_perf` to the URL

It's required if you're using React 15
https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html#profiling-components-with-chrome-timeline

Not required for React 16 though
https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab

Comment: Thanks for your survey.