# 'Timings' tab in Chrome Performance Profiler Missing

Tags: performance, react-native, google-chrome-devtools, profiler, react-devtools

So I was successfully monitoring the performance of my React Native App in the **Timings** section inside the **Performance** Tab of **Chrome Developer Tools**.

All of a sudden upon a particular reload of the app, the **Timings** tab went **missing**.

[image]

I have tried resetting chrome, restarting my computer and changing a bunch of options inside developer tools but nothing seems to work.

Could someone explain what has happened and how I can fix this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seeing this also, did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet. Did you try reinstalling chrome?

Comment: No, haven’t tried yet...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So a user on reddit who goes by ***pie6k*** helped me fix this issue. I have rephrased his response below with a bit of modification that made it work for me.

1. Start Recording
2. Reload the app
3. Do what you want to measure
4. Stop Recording

Yeah it's not the best experience but at least it works.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/g88aj9

Comment: It's pathetic that this is what is needed, but it is what it is. Can confirm that this is working for me as well.